# Безопасно ли отправлять пользовательский header("Location: ... ") ? PHP

Tags: php, header, location

Извините, вопрос откровенно глупый. Но у меня паранойя, поэтому я решился спросить. Короче, суть в том, что на сайте в одном месте происходит вызов функции header вот так:

```
header("Location: $url", true, 301);
```

Причём переменная $url приходит от пользователя. Не спрашивайте почему так. Это нужно.
Дело даже не столько в безопасности. У меня просто вопрос - можно ли каким-то образом отправить несколько заголовков в одной функции header? Важно, чтобы кроме отправки заголовка Location больше ничего не происходило. И неважно что ввёл пользователь.

Comment: для php >=5.1.2 сделали защиту от подобных инъекций

Comment: Вы должны понимать, что с редиректом 301 вы увидите пользователя в этом скрипте ровно 1 раз.

Comment: Именно это мне и нужно :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP 5.1.2 Release Notes](http://php.net/releases/5_1_2.php)

> Header() can no longer be used to send multiple response headers in a single call.
>
> header() больше не может быть использована для отправки нескольких заголовков в одном вызове.

Это специально сделано для защиты от атак, связанных с инъекцией заголовков.

Comment: Спасибо большое